# Серверная программа на Apple Swift (реализация игрового сервера)

Tags: ios, swift, сервер, консоль, apple

Не совсем понятна или возможно ли это вообще на этом языке, может на objective-c... Нужно разработать "демо версия сервера" для игры в виде консольного приложения что получает и отдает сетевые запросы, что-то похожее на игровой сервер но заглушка. От сюда и вопрос на чем и как это пишется гуглил не нашел ответ. Возможно фреймворки или готовые решения?

Comment: [swift-nio](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio) от Apple

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из наиболее популярных Server Side Swift фреймворков можно выделить:

[Vapor](https://vapor.codes/)

[Perfect](https://perfect.org/)

Активно продвигаемая IBM:

[Kitura](https://www.kitura.io/)

На "старте" их было больше, но некоторые были заброшены, некоторые не прижились или совсем не популярны. Что выбрать Вам - можете почитать сравнения, к примеру: [Vapor vs. Kitura](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1323930-vapor-vs-kitura-choosing-a-server-side-swift-framework)